# How to subtract the mean of each variable from the mean of a specific variable

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to subtract the mean of each variable from the mean of a variable named 'birds' and create a new data frame that will contain the results.In my real data frame I have hundreds of variables so I would like to do it automatically.Any Idea how to do so?
I tried with this line of code without the mean function and it works (on the same data frame) :

```
setNames(as.data.frame(cbind(g, mean(dat$birds)-mean(dat))), c(names(dat), paste0(names(dat),'_new')))
```

but I don't understand how to use `mean` as part of the code,I tried:

```
setNames(as.data.frame(cbind(g, mean(dat$birds)-mean(dat))), c(names(dat), paste0(names(dat),'_new')))
```

Here is my toy data frame.

```
dat <- read.table(text = " birds    wolfs     snakes
                    3        9         7
                    3        8         4
                    1        2         8
                    1        2         3
                    1        8         3
                    6        1         2
                    6        7         1
                    6        1         5
                    5        9         7
                    3        8         7
                    4        2         7
                    1        2         3
                    7        6         3
                    6        1         1
                    6        3         9
                    6        1         1   ",header = TRUE)
```

Comment: `mean(dat)` takes the mean of the whole `data.frame`. You probably want `colMeans`.

Comment: Do you want `colMeans(dat)-mean(dat$birds)`

Comment: Thanks @akrun, seems so simple...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I understood your question correctly.
This should create a new object, in this case - just a vector, where mean of "birds" column is substracted from the means of other columns. This should also work for any size of the data frame.

```
mean=mean(dat$birds)
dat2=colMeans(dat[2:dim(dat)[2]])-mean
```

In the future, please provide reproducible example (in your code, object 'g' is not defined) and an example of the expected output, so that it would be clear what you are trying to achieve.